# Tomar valor de input dentro de datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Gente tengo una tabla que carga medicamentos desde la `BD`, la misma tiene un `input` dentro para indicar la cantidad deseada de cada uno, la cuestion es que no puedo tomar el valor introducido en el `input`.

Dejo el codigo por las dudas alguien pudiese darme una mano.

Gracias de antemano.

```
function obtener_medicamentos() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "WebService.asmx/obtenerMedicamentos",
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 1) {
            sinSession()
        } else {
            var dataTableVariable = $("#tbm").DataTable({
                "lengthMenu": [[5], [5]],
                destroy: true,
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    //{ 'data': 'idItem' },
                    { 'data': 'dsItem' },
                    { 'data': 'unidad' },
                    { 'data': 'stock' },
                    { 'defaultContent': '<input type="text" id="cant" CssClass="cant" value="0">' },
                    { 'defaultContent': "<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-info ag' title='Agregar Medicamento'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'> Agregar</i></button>" }
                ],
                "language": { "sUrl": "fonts/datatable_espanol.txt" }
            })
            bServerSide: true;
            bProcessing: true;
            $("#tbm tbody").off('click')
            agregar_med("#tbm tbody", dataTableVariable)
        }
    }, error: function () {
        alertify.alert("Ha ocurrido un error")
    }
})
}

var agregar_med = function (tbody, table) {
$(tbody).on("click", "button.ag", function () {
    //asi me toma siempre 0 que es el valor introducido por defecto al cargar la tabla
    var fila = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data()
    //alert("Id: " + fila.idItem + " Med: " + fila.dsItem + " Unidad: " + fila.unidad + " Stock: " + fila.stock + " Cantidad: " + fila.cantidad )

    //cualquiera de las 2 formas toma el valor del input de la primera fila sin importar que botón apriete
    var dato = table.$('input').val();
    var dato = table.$('#cant').val();
    alert(dato)
})
}
```

Comment: En que momento falla? `fila` se está rellenando bien? Si hasta ahí va bien prueba: `var dato = $('#cant').val();`

Comment: Utiliza parent() en lugar de parents()

Comment: Si utilizo parent,  fila no se carga.
Si uso parents si, pero se carga con los datos iniciales de la tabla, los cuales son llenados desde un webservice por un array

            For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim it As New ItemReceta

                it.idItem = dt.Rows(i)(0)
                it.dsItem = dt.Rows(i)(1)
                it.unidad = dt.Rows(i)(2)
                it.stock = dt.Rows(i)(3)
                it.cantidad = 0

                lis.Add(it)
            Next

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo solucione con esta linea dentro de la función agregar_med()

```
var cant = $(this).parents("tr").find('#cant').val();
```